# How to read eml file contains in eml file using Javamail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an EML file which contains another EML file as an attachment.
When I try to fetch an attachment file using JAVAMAIL API, getDisposition value indicates attachment but `getfileName()` displays `NULL`.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            InputStream source = new FileInputStream("C:\\Mail1496085.eml");
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);
            System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("--------------");
            System.out.println("Body : " +  message.getContent());
            String contentType = message.getContentType();
            if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
System.out.println("Multipart EMail File");
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
            System.out.println("Parts:::"+numberOfParts);
            String wi="IM-67890-PROCESS";
            String saveDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Docs";
            saveDir=saveDir + File.separator+wi;
            boolean file =new File(saveDir).mkdir();
           if (file) {
                  System.out.println("Directory: " + wi + " created");
                 // logger.debug("Directory: " + workItem + " created");
                }

            for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                String disposition=part.getDisposition();
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                    // this part is attachment      
                    String fileName = part.getFileName();
                    String extension="";
                    System.out.println("Attached File Name::"+fileName);
                    saveDir=saveDir + File.separator + fileName;
                    int i=fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
                        if(i>0)
                        {
                            extension=fileName.substring(i+1);
                        }
                     if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("eml"))
                     {
                         part.saveFile(saveDir);
                         extractEML(saveDir, wi);
                         System.out.println("This is a eml file");
                     }
                     else if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("msg"))
                     {
                         part.saveFile(saveDir);
                         extractMSG(saveDir,wi);
                         System.out.println("This is a msg file");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         System.out.println("This is other file");
                     }
                   } else {
                        System.out.println("Not an eml file");
               System.out.println("File Name::"+part.getFileName());
                }
            }
        }
}


public static void extractEML(String emlPath,String wi) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        //String fileName=""; 
        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Docs" + File.separator + wi + File.separator + "EML_PDF";
         boolean file =new File(path).mkdir();
         if(file)
         {
             System.out.println("Folder EML_PDF Created Successfully");
         }
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(emlPath);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);
        System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("Body : " +  message.getContent());
        String contentType = message.getContentType();
        if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
            System.out.println("Multipart EMail File");
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
            System.out.println("Parts:::"+numberOfParts);
            for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                     String fileName = part.getFileName();
                     String extension="";
                     path=path + File.separator + fileName;
                     int i=fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
                     if(i>0)
                     {
                        extension=fileName.substring(i+1);
                     }
                     if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
                     {
                         part.saveFile(path);
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question will be much easier to answer if you edit it and include the code which opens and reads the .eml file.

Answer (score 1):

File names for attachments are optional.  You need to fix your program to work without a file name.

Comment: #Thanks Bill,I got the solution. I want one more solution like could you suggest me how to save all types files(.pdf,doc,docx,jpeg,png,etc) without using if-else condition?In my case I am saving only PDF, but i want to save all types of files.

Comment: Just use MimeBodyPart.saveFile.  It doesn't care what type of file it is, it will save anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, inputStream);
  MimeMessageParser mimeParser = new MimeMessageParser(message);
  mimeParser.parse();
  List<DataSource> dsl =  mimeParser.getAttachmentList();
  for(DataSource ds : dsl) {
  InputStream file = ds.getInputStream();
  }
```